# how to force as mandatory a String when binding an application.properties file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, application.properties

i have something like that..

in file application.properties

```
  input.param.resolution=high
  input.param.size=1024
```

in a configuration class

```
  @Configuration
  public class FirstConfiguration {

  @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("input.param")
        Data buildDataBean() {
        return new Data();
     }
  }
```

my pojo

```
  public class Data {

      String resolution;
      String size;

     // getters and setters 
  }
```

I'd like to unauthorize binding when my String are not provided in properties file.. (and make Spring launch an exception)

```
    input.param.resolution=<nothing-here>
    input.param.size=<nothing-here>
```

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try validating it as follows:

```java
@Validated
public class Data {
    @NotNull
    String resolution;

    @NotNull
    String size;

   // getters and setters 
}
```

If you don't have it there already you need to add the following dependency to your project:

```xml
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: i tried but it didn't have any effect :-(